# Website background color automatic gradient applied

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am running into a problem where I have apply my background color which is a solid color but for some reason I am getting a gradient that occurs (desired color slowly turns to white at the bottom of the page) as shown below:

[image]

The below is the code where I am defining my webpage including the background color:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import NavBar from '../../components/nav'

export default function LandingPage() {
return (

<body className = "bg-brand-bg">
  <NavBar />
  <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
  
  <div className="font-mono px-4">
    <h1 className="text-6xl">Sample?</h1>
    <p className="py-4">Sample.</p>
    <p>Sample!</p>
  </div>

  <form method="post" class="bg-white p-4 flex justify-between items-center rounded-lg">
      <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" class="flex-grow mr-4 p-2 rounded placeholder-gray-500"></input>
      <button class="bg-brand-red-dark hover:bg-logo-red-light text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
        Stay in the Loop
      </button>
  </form>

  
</main>
</body>
```

The below is the tailwindcss config file where I have defined my custom colors:

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image'

function NavBar() {
return (
<nav className="flex items-center">
  <Image 
    src = "/Logo/logo.png"
    width = {100}
    height= {100}
    alt = "Logo"
  />
  <div className="flex flex-col items-start">
      <p className="font-mono text-2xl font-black">Sample</p>
      <p className="font-mono text-sm font-black">Sample</p>
  </div>

  
  
</nav>
);
}


 export default NavBar;
```

Below is my configuration file aswell:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: {
        'brand-bg': '#FFEA9C',
        'logo-blue': '#069AF0',
        'logo-red-dark': '#E5191C',
        'logo-red-light': '#FF3129',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Any help on this would help alot. I don't even know where to begin with this one.

Let me know if I should gather more background information.

Thanks

Comment: Your Tailwind configuration is incorrect. It seems like you are exporting a React component, but you should actually export an object. Consider checking [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration) for the correct format.

Comment: Hey @Wongjn 

I appreciate your comment. I am not exactly sure how to check or address your main comment about exporting an object. However, I did look into the documentation that you linked and check my configuration file to ensure that the imports of the files was done correctly. I have updated the main post to show this. However my problem is still persisting. Any other insights you can provide? Much appreciated.

Comment: Consider checking for other CSS that may be applying the gradient. Also consider checking for any browser extensions that may be applying the gradient.

Comment: I have tried on multiple browsers and have tried changing the color to something else and the same effect appears. This is a fresh install of tailwindcss and next.js so I don't think that there should be something in the setting that is would specify having background take on a gradient.

Comment: Ok , so when I apply the background color to my navbar and main tags separately the gradient disappears. I also tried to remove the navbar component and apply the background color to the main tag the same problem persists. Is there something special about the main tags that causes this behaviour?